# How to separate a column into two tab delimited columns in a text file

Tags: awk, sed, multiple-columns

I have an input file that has 5 columns, but I need to separate the 5th column into two so the output file has a total of 6.

My input file data looks like this:

```
chrX    100629986   100630758   -   ENSG00000000003.14.IntrontENST00000373020.8.Intron  
chrX    100630866   100632484   -   ENSG00000000003.14.IntrontENST00000373020.8.Intron  
chrX    100632568   100633404   -   ENSG00000000003.14.IntrontENST00000373020.8.Intron
```

You notice that the 5th column has a similar structure in all my data so what I want to do is make my 5th column contain **"ENSG00000000003.14.Intron"** and my 6th column contain **"tENST00000373020.8.Intron"**

However not all my data has the .Intron tag such as:

```
chrX    100597503   100597531   +   ENSG00000000005.5tENST00000485971.1
```

But you'll notice all my data as the **"t"** and thus this is what I want to use to separate out these columns. I'm unsure how to do this for data that has several hundred thousand lines, and manually doing this would take way too long. I also need the entire file to be tab delimited so that I can continue further processing this data.

Thanks to everyone in advance,

Comment: Is the "t" character present somewhere else in the file? Is it always preceded by ENSG + digits and dots?

Comment: Outside of the word "Intron" that is sometimes a suffix for some lines in column 5 as shown in the original post, then no it does not.

Comment: Is the "t" always followed by ENST + something?

Comment: Yes always ENST and some variation of numbers after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sed to insert the tab:

```
sed 's/tENST/\t&/' < input > output
```

Every tENST string is replaced by a tab + the string.

For some `sed` versions, you might try `$'s/tENST/\t&/'` instead (i.e. prepend a `$`).

Comment: Outputs the following: 

    chrX 100629986 100630758 -     ENSG00000000003.14.IntronttENST00000373020.8.Intron 
    chrX 100630866 100632484 -     ENSG00000000003.14.IntronttENST00000373020.8.Intron 
    chrX 100632568 100633404 - ENSG00000000003.14.IntronttENST00000373020.8.Intron

EDIT: Yikes don't know how to format code in the comments.

Comment: @System: What OS are you on?

Comment: Mac OS X version 10.9.5

Comment: Is the update required? The mac is used by the entire lab so I am not allowed to preform any updates without permission from the PI and he's out for the day.

Comment: Wow that's really embarassing. That worked flawlessly thank you! I've gone ahead and accepted the answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

With awk, you would write

```
awk -F"\t" '{sub(/tENST/, FS "tENST", $5); print}' file > output
```

Comment: As you see, only one accepted answer is possible, and choroba's is the better answer.